# Trouble with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

OK, first-off I admit MySQL Syntax has never been my strongest point. So, here I am.

**Urls :**

```
ID   Url                              Code
===============================================
1    http://www.google.com            Abcd
2    http://www.freetemplates4u.com   Efgh
3    ...
```

**Posts :**

```
ID  Title            Address
===============================================
1   Some Title 1     http://mize.it/Abcd
2   Some Title 2     http://mize.it/Efgh
3   ...
```

---

I want to create a query to fetch the following table

```
Title             Url
=======================================================
Some Title 1      http://www.google.com
Some Title 2      http://www.freetemplates4u.com
```

---

In a few words :

- Take the `Url`-`Code` pairs from `Urls` table
- Search for `http://mize.it/`+`Code` in the `Posts` table (in the `Address` field)
- Combine the final `Title` and `Url` in a result table.

I know it has something to do with joins and concatenation, but I'm definitely lost.

---

**SIDENOTE :** I don't care neither about my current database's structure, nor about performance issues. All I want is to transfer existing data, from the existing database (without having to alter it), to my new website's database (under a totally different format/structure).

Comment: Why not store everything in one table? Or, if for some reason you can't do this, add `Code` t posts so it could be external key for `Urls`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your DB-Design, this query will have a poor performance since mysql has to do a full tablescan.

Try adding a code column in your Posts table hat has the right value (populate it on insert/update) and add an index to Code (both tables).

Now you should be able to do.

```
SELECT Posts.Title, Urls.Url
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN Urls ON Post.Code = Urls.Code
```

**Update:**

If the first part of the url is always the same, this will work

```
SELECT Post.Title, Urls.Url
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN Urls ON Post.Adress = CONCAT('http://mize.it/', Urls.Code)
```

Comment: I don't really care about performance. I'm just trying to get all data from an existing website's database, so that I can process it and re-enter it to my new website (in a totally different format).

Comment: Awesome! Great, great, great. Although the final query (I just created) is much much more complex than the example in the original question (with cross-db references, etc), you've definitely pointed me to the right direction. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
SELECT p.title,x.url
FROM Posts p 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT url, CONCAT('http://mize.it/',code) AS xcode FROM Urls ) x  
ON (x.xcode = p.address)
```

[Working DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54199/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approch, it took a while for me to test it.

Since your `Address` field contains complete url and we only need to match what is after `/` so we can replace actual url with nothing (I assume url is always the same) and have string ready to be matched with `Code` field.

```
SELECT b.Title, a.URL
FROM Url a
LEFT JOIN Posts b
ON a.Code = REPLACE(b.Address, 'http://mize.it/', '')
ORDER BY a.ID ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

Check following query.

```
select m1.Url, m2.Title from Urls as m1, Posts as m2 

where m2.address like 'http://mize.it/%'
```